# Retrieve Android Facebook Token for Business

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am trying to retrieve the token_for_business from the GraphUser that I have already gotten from a ME request.  It is coming back null each time.  I'm able to successfully retrieve many other bits of information from the ME request. For example:

```
public String getEmail() {
    if (Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().contains("email")) {
        return (String) mUser.getProperty("email");
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I've verified several times that the Facebook Dashboard is set up to use the Token for Business.  I'm aware that I could try to query the Business Manager API directly, however I'm already chaining several API calls and would prefer to use the data that I am supposed to already have.

```
public String getTokenForBusiness() {
    return (String) mUser.getProperty("token_for_business");
}
```

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) says that this property exists given that the user is logged into the app.  Of course, the ME request is made only after the Session state has been recognized to be open, so to my understanding, the user is logged in.

Is there a permission that I'm missing? Are there any other stipulations to using this property?

**UPDATE**: I tried using the Business Mapping API.  It works as far as recognizing the app as a valid part of our business, but it does not contain the token_for_business that I need.  So this path will not work.  I also tried accessing the token after the entire login process was completed just to be sure that I wasn't calling it before something was finished, however I still get a null value for the token.  I additionally tried using this request:

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/{user-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            Log.i("TFB", response.toString());
            Log.i("TFB", (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("token_for_business") + "");
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Of course, I replaced {user-id} with an actual user id.  This response contained the information that I would expect, excluding the token_for_business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't an ideal solution, but after experimenting with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), I came up with this.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "token_for_business");

new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(final Response response) {
                if (response != null) {
                     GraphUser user = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphUser.class);
                     Log.i("TFB", user.getProperty("token_for_business"));
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
```

The problem with this solution is that you will need to add all aspects of the GraphUser to the "fields" parameter.  For example if you need to know a user's first name and gender the appropriate bundle would contain:

```
bundle.putString("fields", "token_for_business,first_name,gender");
```

So for someone who doesn't mind having an extra call it would probably better be to keep the token_for_business separate from the ME request, just in case Facebook updates their SDK/API and breaks this solution sometime in the future.